# Time complexity of a de-duping algorithm

Tags: javascript, time-complexity, complexity-theory

Here is a function for removing duplicates from an array.

```js
function dedupe(arr) {
    var seen = {};
    arr.forEach((e,i)=>{
        if (seen[e]) {
            arr.splice(i, 1);
        }
        seen[e] = true;
    });
    return arr;
}

console.log(dedupe([1, 2, 1, 3, 4]));
```

I am interested in the time complexity of this function.

If we assume that `Array` is backed by a real array, does that the time complexity can be analysed as follows?

- allocation of `seen`: O(1)
- enumerate all elements: O(n)
- removal of a duplicate: O(n) (because re-allocation required item by item?)
- return O(1)

So is this an O(n^2) algorithm?

**Edit:**

Corrected for indexing issue.

```js
function dedupe(arr) {
    var seen = {};
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        const e = arr[i];
        if (seen[e]) {            
            arr.splice(i, 1);
            i--; // we have modified the array and need to continue from the current index
        }
        seen[e] = true;
    }
    return arr;
}

console.log(dedupe([1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 4, 7, 6, 7, 7, 7, 1, 5]));
```

For those upset by the performance of the above, this is O(N) I think.

I wanted to de-dupe in-place. Use of `Set` maintains the order across host environments.

```js
function dedupe(arr) {
    var seen = new Set();
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        seen.add(arr[i]);
    }
    arr.length = 0; // empty the array
    return arr.concat(...seen.keys());
}

console.log(dedupe([1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 4, 7, 6, 7, 7, 7, 1, 5]));
```

Comment: Take care of editing an array while you do a `forEach`. If you test `[1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 4, 7, 6, 7, 7, 7, 1, 5]` you`ll have some bugs

Comment: I think it would be an O(n) algorithm if you used a smarter way to build the deduped array instead of splice.

Comment: @dloeda What will the behavior be if I modify an array being iterated over with foreach like this? Is it that the index value gets out of sync?

Comment: @BenAston When you remove the first item, the array gets shorter, but then index you get from forEach doesn't change. So you will point next item you want  when you do `arr.splice(i, 1)`

Comment: @BenAston why dont you just make arr empty after loop and then assign the keys in seen, you won't need to use splice in this way. It will be O(n).

Comment: Infact I have just refactored it as you suggest! My question is whether this implementation is O(N^2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to use the Javascript [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). You could simply do this:

```
const removeDuplicates = array => (new Set(array)).values()
```

This will return an iterator, and not an array, however this can easily be fixed. Also, sets are **not** yet supported in most browsers. The complexity of this should be O(n).

Another approach more similar to yours (but probably identical to the Set, since I'm gonna guess it's implemented using the same underlying structure) would be like this:

```
const removeDuplicates = array =>
    Object.keys(array.reduce((agg, x) => { agg[x] = true; return agg }, {}))
```

The time complexity of this should be O(m+n) where m will be the number of unique items, which will always be <= n, therefore O(n).

Also, the time complexity you worked out seems correct.

Answer (score 0):

You could save `seen` by filtering by index:

```js
var t1 = [1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 4];
function uniqueList(list) {
    return list.filter(function (value, index, arr) {
        return list.indexOf(value) == index;
    });
}
console.log(t1);
console.log(uniqueList(t1));
```

Comment: I am aiming to make the algorithm O(N) - this would preclude that by making the presence-check O(N) I think.

Answer (score 0):

My answer, builds a new array. Maybe is O(n).

```js
function dedupe(arr) {
    var result = [];
    var seen = {};
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        const e = arr[i];
        if (seen[e]) {            
            //skip
        } else {
            seen[e] = true;
            result.push(e);
        }
        
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(dedupe([1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 4, 7, 6, 7, 7, 7, 1, 5]));
```